# CodeIgnigter - How to store and access user login session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller that is used to create a user login session with the following code:

```
    public function account(){
    $data = array();
    if($this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn')){
        $data['user'] = $this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('userId')));

        //Create session
        $newdata = array(
            'username'  => $user['name'],
            'email'     => $user['email'],
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

        //load the view
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        //redirect('pages/view/');
    }else{
        redirect('users/login');
    }
}
```

Problem occurs when I try to check from this or any other of my controllers the session data and it always returns false. Not sure what it is that Im doing wrong. If I pass this

> $data['user']

to a View as data, Im able to access the name and email, but I cant access it on the controller

Comment: You're setting the `$newdata` array with `$user['name']` and $user['email']`, but I don't see where `$user` is coming from. Did you mean to use `$data['name']`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I believe your problem is here.

```
$newdata = array(
    'username'  => $user['name'],
    'email'     => $user['email'],
);
```

The variable `$user` has not been set in the controller, at least not in the code you show. I think this is what you need

```
$newdata = array(
    'username'  => $data['user']['name'],
    'email'     => $data['user']['email'],
);
```

A suggestion, not related to your problem, regarding getting session data. With CI >= v3.0.0 you can obtain an item of session data like this.

```
$this->session->isUserLoggedIn;
```

The code behind this method is smaller and you type less to get the same return that `$this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn')` provides.

`userdata()` is a legacy method kept only for backwards compatibility with older applications.

Answer (score 0):

**First, you need store session data** 
`

```
$sedata = array(
        'user'  => 1,
        'username'     => $username,
        'userid'     => $dbrow->id,
        'mobile_phone'     => $dbrow->mobile_phone,
        'success'   => 'Successfully loggedin!',
        'logged_in' => TRUE
    );
$this->session->set_userdata($sedata);
```

`**Now you get session data like :**`

```
$this->session->userdata('user');
$this->session->userdata('userid');
```

`